# wrong time passed to callback called by requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, console.log, requestanimationframe

I'm using a simple `requestAnimationFrame` loop which starts immediately after the DOM is created.
I needed to use the time argument which is passed to the callback, but I noticed that in the first few frames the time is wrong. Here's what happens when I run this code on firefox :

```js
function loop(time) {

    console.log(time);

    // do something with time to animate the canvas 

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

[image: console]

I can skip those 3 first frames with a simple condition, but why does it behave that way?

Comment: What makes you think those times are wrong? Are you sure there isn't a navigation taking place and you're preserving the logs between navigations? Are you sure the `undefined` console output is coming from your `requestAnimationFrame` callback?

Comment: These are the last calls from your previous page, before you did refresh the page. Just an artifact from the console. And for the first `undefined`, you probably initialise your rAF loop as a simple call without an argument e.g `animate();` instead of `requestAnimationFrame(animate);`.

Comment: @jacob No I'm not preserving logs between navigations .
@Kaiido The solution to the `undefined` problem is exactly what you said , I feel stupid for not being able to solve that easy problem on my own .
As for the first two console logs , they weren't from the running script .

Comment: Instead of using console.log, push these values in an Array, then log that Array. Are these values there?

Comment: The artifact logs are not present in the array , can you please explain why is `console.log` behaving like that ? I couldn't find infos about it .

Comment: There is no real standards as to how the console should work and behave. That's just an FF "bug", nothing too serious though... and has already been reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1588959

Comment: To settle if it's a hold over console.log or not, add another console log as the first line of JS on your page eg; `console.log('start')`. It would be very helpful if you'd provide code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the the question to add the animation loop , but it's just a simple requestAnimationFrame loop , nothing special . And for the `console.log('start')` , it gets logged after the artifact logs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1588959), caused by the fact they clear the console in the `will-navigate` state instead of doing it in `navigated`.

So indeed, you may get logs that did happen in between these two states persist on the next session, but that's just in the console, your code won't see these.